# What sense it has to set copyright info when creating app in iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

It is not straightforward that the owner of the product is who uploads the binary?

Why do I have to set the year at copyright field? Next year I have to update it?

In which case I can use copyright info? If somebody steels the my computer, my binary, than I can sue him? Can copyright info use against me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple **does not assume** who owns the copyright. The copyright field is provided for you to explicitly state who claims copyright for the uploaded product.

Apple's [iTunes Connect documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html) states:

> **Copyright *(required)*** The name of the person or entity that owns the exclusive rights to the app, preceded by the year the rights were obtained (for example, 2014 Example, Inc.). The copyright symbol is added automatically.

Copyright is a [large and complex issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Copyright_law). If you are unsure or have legal questions, you are best contacting a legal expert for the jurisdictions you intend to operate within.

You may also find this question helpful, [Understanding copyright field in the iTunes Connect app submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343699/understanding-copyright-field-in-the-itunes-connect-app-submission).